# Business trip to Germany with a multiple entry visa to Ireland?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, ireland, multiple-entry

A one year multiple entry visa to Ireland (as I was invited on a business trip // in April) was issued to me as I presented invitation letters to Germany (in May) & France (in June) besides my initial invitation to Ireland (of course). At first, I thought that Ireland is part of the Schengen zone but it turned out to be a little bit more complicated than that.
Question is: can I make to Germany & France with this kind of visa?

P.S.: Having a Lebanese passport doesn't give any kind of visa privileges.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: No.

Since Ireland and Great Britain maintain a common area and [have opted out of the Schengen Aquis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#EU_member_states_with_opt-outs) Ireland's Visa holds no force anywhere in the Schengen Area.

So in order to enter Germany or France you will need a separate Schengen Visa.

Comment: +1 Although, even though there is a common travel area, you will still won't be able to get into the UK with an Irish visa either.